# Ansible with host specific files, but fallback to default files

Tags: ansible

I'm currently trying to get used to Ansible but I'm failing to achieve what seems to be a common use-case:

Lets say I have have a role `nginx` in `roles/nginx` and and one task is to setup a custom default page:

```
- name: install nginx default page
  copy:
    src: "index.html"
    dest: /var/www/html/
    owner: root
    mode: 0644
```

Ansible will look for the file in:

```
roles/nginx/files
roles/nginx
roles/nginx/tasks/files
roles/nginx/tasks
files
./
```

Now for some reason a single host should receive a completely different file. 
I know I could alter the file src path to `src: "{{ inventory_hostname }}/index.html"` but then it would search in host-specific directories only.

Is there a way to alter the search paths so that Ansible will look for files in host-specific directories first but fall-back to common directories?

I don't want to decide if files might need to be host-specific when writing roles. I'd rather like to overwrite the role default files without altering the base role at all.

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"Is there a way to alter the search paths so that Ansible will look for files in host-specific directories first but fall back to common directories?"***

A: In general, it is not possible to change the [search paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible). But, with [first_found](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/first_found.html#first-found-return-first-file-found-from-list) it is possible to define how a specific file shall be searched. For example,

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: "{{ lookup('first_found', findme) }}"
        dest: /scratch/tmp/
        owner: root
        mode: 0644
      vars:
        findme:
          - "{{ inventory_hostname }}/index.html"
          - "{{ role_path }}/files/index.html"
          - "{{ role_path }}/files/defaults/index.html"
```